# Why is my upload error message only received by Edge?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, cross-browser, jquery-file-upload, ajax-upload

I use MultipartConfig to handle file upload with a Servlet and send an error message if the file is to large:

```
       private void doUpload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

            Part filePart;
            try {
                filePart = request.getPart("file");
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                System.out.println("File To Large");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
                PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
                writer.println("failure:filetobig");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                return;
            }
         ... (file handling) ...
        }
```

If I use the Servlet with Jquery-File-Upload (Ajax based) and the file-size exceeds maxFileSize, Edge returns the correct error-message with a status code of 413 and a ready-state of 4. If I do the same with Firefox or Chrome I receive a status-code of 0, a ready-state of 0 and the network-tab in dev-tools shows no answer is received.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57eOV.png)

In Firefox the bitrate switches from negative to positive and Chrome return NaN after a while. No matter which browser I use, the `System.out.println("File To Large");` is executed. If I execute the Upload-Request with cURL the correct error-message is returned.

My MultipartConfig to test this:

```
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 30, // 30 MB
        maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1000 // 1000 MB
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: The Server reset the connection because maxSwallowSize is set too low.

See: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

Weirdly enough Edge doesn't care for that and displays the correct message!?